# How to mark a post as viewed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model, `Post`, which has a field called `is_viewed`, which is false when a `Post` is created.

What is the best way to set `is_viewed` to true when a post is shown to the user?

Currently, I am having to do this:

```
class PostsController..

  def show
    #find the post
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])

    if !@post.is_viewed?
      #mark as viewed
      @post.update_attribute(:is_viewed, true)
      #find the post (again)
      @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

In order to load the post only once, I could do this:

```
if !@post.viewed?
  if @post.update_attribute(:is_viewed, true)
    #simply update the viewed to true, "in memory" so that
    #the view's erb can use the correct value of the "is_viewed" variable
    @post.viewed = true
  end
end
```

But is that the right thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ruby isn't very rubyish. Typically one doesn't use 'is_' as a prefix as ruby allows method names to end with a question mark. Assuming your field is a boolean you can use `@post.viewed?` as a shorthand.

Anyway to answer your question, because of ActiveRecord::Dirty there's really no need to check the current state. If you call `@post.save` on a post for which `@post.changed?` is false, no update query will be run. So:

```
@post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
@post.viewed = true
@post.save
```

You don't say why your code reloads the post so I'm going to assume that's bogus. Ruby has an `unless` keyword so you can replace constructions like `if !expr` with `unless expr`.

Also, ruby code looks best indented with 2 spaces :-)

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I am setting viewed to true when the post is shown (i.e. the code executes in the show action of the posts controller). If I use your code, I would be setting viewed to true, no matter if it has already been set and thus would write to the table every time a post is shown. Plus why write out all of the fields when only one of them is to be updated? Ps. Updated my code to show some context. Also, a second reload is needed so that when the view is rendered, the view's .erb can also know the actual state of the viewed field.

Comment: Perhaps you could try reading my answer. Like it says, because of AR::Dirty there will be no write unless one is necessary. And since you want to mark posts as viewed the first time they are, the subsequent views will have no effect. In that sense, the action is idempotent.

Comment: Thank you, noodle. I am now using `update_attribute` to do the update, and that is working in a similar manner as well.